Structural comparison in generic
I tried the following little experiment:
type Equal<X,Y> = 
    (<T>()=> T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends (<T>()=> T extends Y ? 1 : 2)
  ? true
  : false;
type Res = Equal<any, 1>; // type Res = false

I thought the Equal<X,Y> would become:
type Equal<X,Y> = 
    (<T>()=> T extends any ? 1 : 2) extends (<T>()=> T extends 1 ? 1 : 2)


First function: <T>() => T extends any ? 1 : 2 → Always returns 1 (since everything extends any).

Second function: <T>() => T extends 1 ? 1 : 2 → Returns 1 only for T = 1, otherwise 2.


thus, I thought it means that first function is ()=>1 and second function is ()=>1|2
But the following results left me confused:
type FuncTest<F1, F2> = F1 extends F2 ? true : false;
type Res = FuncTest<()=>1, ()=>1|2> // type Res = true

The return type 1 of the function passed as a type argument is compatible with 1|2, so the above result is understandable. However then, I don't understand why the first result was false.
What I've tried:
I asked Chat GPT a question related to this, and I figured out that it is related to structural type system. and I understand like this:
In the case of (<T>()=> T extends any ? 1 : 2) extends (<T>()=> T extends 1 ? 1 : 2), the result is about what the type of T is, so TypeScript compares their structure(whether they behave identically). thus, the result is false because they don't behave identically.
In the case of FuncTest<()=>1, ()=>1|2>, the functions passed as type parameter always return 1 and 1|2. so TypeScript check only type compatibility.
Did I understand correctly?

No, it's the opposite of structural typing. The point of <T>()=>T extends X?1:2 is to force TS to defer evaluation of the type. T extends X?1:2 is a distributive conditional type, and TS waits until the fn is called to evaluate it. So it can't verify that <T>()=>T extends X?1:2 and <T>()=>T extends Y?1:2 are compatible because it doesn't evaluate them. Thus it usually rejects. UNLESS X and Y are identical, and then TS sees that those are the same type, nominally and not structurally. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll turn this into an answer. If not, what's missing?

No, the Equal utility type, as introduced in a comment on microsoft/TypeScript#27024 is an attempt to implement a type-level identity or strict equality operator. This is not structural typing. Two types that are merely structurally equivalent might not show as "equal" with this test:
type A = { x: string, y: string }
type B = { x: string } & { y: string }
type Res = Equal<A, B>; // false

Here A and B have the same exact structure, but they are not considered to be "equal".

The whole point of the strange generic function using a distributive conditional type like <T>()=>T extends X?1:2 is to try to get TypeScript not to actually evaluate X at all.  Generic conditional types tend to be deferred; that type is a function where TypeScript doesn't know what T will be until the function is called, and only then could it determine whether T extends X is true or not. Since this is just a type and nobody ever calls that function, TypeScript never evaluates the type fully. It just keeps it as an opaque "black box", <T>()=>T extends X?1:2.
When comparing two black boxes <T>()=>T extends X?1:2 and <T>()=>T extends Y?1:2, TypeScript will usually be unable to see those as related at all, unless it thinks those are the same black box. The only way that could happen is if X and Y are represented identically.
Therefore the Equal utility type is essentially probing TypeScript's internal representation of the X and Y types to see if they're the same or not. And such probing, while potentially informative, isn't really the sort of thing you should be doing in general. It's implementation-dependent, meaning that in some future version of TypeScript, Equal<A, B> might change from false to true or vice versa, depending on some detail of the TypeScript type checker.

The ChatGPT response about structural typing is a red herring. As of the time I'm writing this, generative AI  is not really a useful resource for Stack Overflow questions like this. AI-generated answers are quite likely to be fundamentally incorrect. The only way to tell the difference between a good AI-generated answer and a bad one is to already have expertise in the relevant subject, or to be able to test the answer directly. If you're asking about something you don't already know about and cannot test yourself, then you should probably refrain from asking AI.
Playground link to code

Thanks for the answer and the advice on AI learning. It's much clearer thanks to a detailed explanation of the purpose of the Equal utility type and how it works under the hood. however, I don't know what is 'opaque blob'. Could you tell me what is 'opaque blob' or refer me to link related of it?

By "opaque blob" I mean that it is unevaluated. If I changed that to "black box" would that make more sense?

Oh, I found out. I thought it was terminology. Thank you!
